# Can we store only webelements as instance variables in interface using @findBy annotations

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, annotations

Once we declare **Webelements** of one page in **interfaces** than It would be easy to get elements everywhere in our full project for writing selenium automation scripts. Please suggest how to do it. I am getting this error **"The blank final field title_page may not have been initialized"** while creating interface as below:

```
public interface PageElements {

    @FindBy(css="h2")
    public static WebElement title_page;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What your doing is wrong. You can't have such statements in interfaces like this:

```
public static WebElement title_page;
```

without `title_page` initialized.

> Once we declare Webelements of one page in interfaces than It would be
>   easy to get elements everywhere in our full project for writing
>   selenium automation scripts

You can achieve the same by splitting the pages *logically* and follow inheritance pattern in Java.

Say for example, if your automating SO site, then you can create an `HeaderPage` which does have all elements those in *header* of the page. Example:

```
class HeaderPage{

    @FindBy(css="any")
    protected static WebElement review;

}
```

once you have this, you can *reuse* them in other header pages, by extending `HeaderPage`. As SO can have an page object called `SONavigationPage` which can be like this:

```
class SONavigationPage extends HeaderPage
{
     //have access to review element. 
}
```

This the nice way to reuse the elements;

Comment: Thanks Ant!! This is correct to extends that single class but I wanted to use multiple classes(multiple Page's elements) in child class(Single page class) and I think that is possible only when I will use interfaces.. Please let me know how can I achieve this..??

Answer (score 0):

You need the this

```
   //initialised elements to use
   PageFactory.initElements(driver, page);
```

See here for further readings: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory
Hope this helps

Comment: How can I do this in interfaces??

Comment: If you understand what interfaces are then you should fine a way

 public interface PageEelemnts{
  
  @FindBy(how= How.ID, using ="h3")
  public static WebElement anElement =null;
  
  public static void initElement(){
  PageFactory.initElements(driver, OverFlow.class);
  
  
  }
 
 }